# Reboot as last step in vdproj, how can I add it?

Tags: windows-installer, vdproj

How can I add the reboot action to a vdproj?

I need an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file which restart the PC at the end of the installation.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the "REBOOT" property with the value "Force" which will prompt the user to reboot once setup is complete, or automatically reboot if there is no user interface.

If you cannot do this in the vdjproj then just use Orca to edit the Property table of the MSI once the setup is built.

If you want to force a reboot, you can set REBOOT=Force and REBOOTPROMPT=Suppress so that the user is not prompted.

Alternatively you can use the `ForceReboot` action to reboot during the middle of  installation or `ScheduleReboot` to schedule a reboot once the installation is complete. Again either of these actions can be added using Orca if you cannot do so in the vdjproj.

You can do something like this using the following VBS

```
Dim installer, database, view, result
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase ("setup.msi", 1)
Set view = database.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('REBOOT', 'Force')")
view.Execute
database.Commit
Set database = nothing
```

Comment: Thank you.
How can I add the ForceReboot action to the vdproj by means of Visual Studio 2008? 
What is Orca?

Comment: Orca is one of the tools that comes with the Windows Installer SDK. I'm not familar with Visual Studio (I just deal with MSI, I don't code) so I can't help you there sorry.

Comment: Is there a simple way to add a property automatically in a Visual Studio post build event ? (so I need a command line)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution based on [saschabeaumont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592/saschabeaumont)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340145/reboot-as-last-step-in-vdproj-how-can-i-add-it/342926#342926).

To automatically modify the .msi to prompt for restart every time I build an installer:

1. Create a file named "AddRebootPrompt.vbs" in the folder where the .vdproj deployment project file is located, with the VB script listed below.
2. Locate the deployment project in the Visual Studio solution explorer, right-click and go 'Properties'.
3. In the PostBuildEvent property, paste the following to run the script after building the installer project:

`cscript "$(ProjectDir)AddRebootPrompt.vbs" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"`

**AddRebootPrompt.vbs content:**

```
Dim installer, database, view, result
Dim strPathMsi 

If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript AddRebootPrompt.vbs <path to MSI>"
    WScript.Quit -1
End If

strPathMsi = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (strPathMsi, 1)
Set view = database.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('REBOOT', 'Force')")

WScript.Echo "Adding forced reboot prompt to install sequence."

view.Execute
database.Commit
WScript.Quit 0
```

If successful, you will see "Adding forced reboot prompt to install sequence." in your Build Output log window when building the installer project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reboot, Windows Installer should detect it automatically. If you want to reboot as you are too lazy to start services manually, you will need to find some other way (I do not know of any easy way).

Comment: In my case Windows Installer does not detect it automatically.